# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root’@host

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

couldn't access database with error message:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root’@‘xxx.ne.jp'(using password: YES)
```

I have this php code.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=xxx.ne.jp';
$user = 'root';
$password ='0123';

try{
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I can login to phpmyadmin with same username and password(root/0123).
why?
Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the actual grant tables yet?

Answer (score -2):

Here is the basic PDO connection example:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

So include the missing **host name**:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;host=xxx.ne.jp';
$user = 'root';
$password ='0123';

try{
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Change `localhost` if running site on another host.